# How to transfer files from Windows to Ubuntu on disk

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-8-preview

Ok, so I have a PC running Windows 8 that I recently decided to try the new reset option on.  Mid way through the reset, the computer shut itself down and now when it opens, it shows an error message saying that the file: windows\system32\winload.exe could not be found.  I searched online and found that you can launch the files from the computer from a disk with the Ubuntu system on it.  I downloaded the software on the disk and booted the computer from the disk which got me to the software on the disk.  The problem is, I looked through all the files and I can't find where the files that are saved on the windows system as documents and pictures are.  (I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on the disk - NOT downloaded to the system)  Please help me out with this and thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot from Ubuntu, Mount the Windows partition and then find where the file is located. (Ubuntu should do this automatically or at least show an icon or an option in the file-manager to mount the partition).

As noted in a comment:

> Click on Computer on the Ubuntu desktop, and you will see icons for
>   the hard drive, the optical drive, and most likely filesystem (The
>   LiveCD in RAM). Click on the hard drive. That will mount it. You will
>   then be able to browse through the files.

Then you can put the new file in place.

Comment: how would I mount the Windows partition? I don't see anything in the file manager to mount the partition

Comment: Click on Computer on the Ubuntu desktop, and you will see icons for the hard drive, the optical drive, and most likely filesystem (The LiveCD in RAM).  Click on the hard drive.  That will mount it.  You will then be able to browse through the files.

Comment: thank you this helped me greatly!  I already backed up those files that I needed and am currently doing a complete system restore back to windows 7.  Thanks!

Comment: @BonGart added the text of your comment to my answer. Thanks